# Aligning Bullet w/Text in Recent Post Widget Extended Plugin

Tags: wordpress, list

I'm using Wordpress>Atahualpa Theme>Recent Posts Widget Extended on my site [toawaken.org](http://toawaken.org).

Recent Posts are listed in the r.h. sidebar. I have added a "bullet" (disc) in front of each Post title. When I did so, it threw the spacing off.

If you link to my site, you will see for some reason the added bullet is forcing the text to appear one line below the bullet, instead of right next to it, on the same line as the bullet, as it should. I want the post's title to line up on the same line as the bullet, not one line below it. I tried adjusting margins/padding in the CSS editor, but no margin/padding combination changed this. Nor did changing the div list-style-position from inside to outside:

```
div.widget ul li {
    display: list-item !important;
    list-style: disc !important;
    list-style-position: inside;
    color: #2D85BA;
}
```

If anyone could please check the sidebar on my site and offer a remedy, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin seems to have a *clearfix* implemented in the `<li>` elements, and it's pushing headers to the next line. You can override it with this CSS:

```
.rpwe-clearfix:before, .rpwe-clearfix:after {
    content: none;
}
```

*As a side note*, try not to use so much `!important` expression in your stylesheets. You'll end up having more and more difficulties changing the CSS rules. If you want to everride certain rule, you use a selector with just a bit stronger **specificity** than the one you want to change.
You can read more about selectors' specificity [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Comment: Thanks, Tomek, that fixed it immediately! Wow, I like this site, got my answer in under 15 minutes. I had posted this question to the author of this plugin over 2 weeks ago, nothing, nada.

All those !important in the CSS were put there by the plugin developer, not me...they're built into his CSS. He thinks it was "important" to have them all in there, so he obviously doesn't know much about specificities. Thanks

Comment: Ha, that is true, Stack Overflow is a gem ;) Consider accepting / upvoting the answer when you're positive it did solved your issue. (good one about the "importance" of those importants)

Comment: where do I accept/upvote your answer?? not seeing that

Comment: And once again, you can find the answer on the Stack Exchange network ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work - actually they recommend to wait a bit, so do as you wish, I won't hold it against you ;)